# KendoWindow not firing open on second call

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

`See http://jsfiddle.net/BigAl4444/j1v6oxo4/4/`

The open() function is firing on the first press of the 'Delete record' button, however it seems to be failing on the 2nd (and all subsequent) presses.

The first time you press 'Delete', the text "CUSTOM MESSAGE" is displayed.  Subsequent presses results in the words "CUSTOM MESSAGE" not being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider moving the `var kendoWindow` outside of the click handler.
This will not only solve your issue, but will clean up the HTML that is getting created under the hood each time the button is pressed.

The issue you're experiencing is because each click of the button is creating an entirely new modal, & duplicating the HTML each time...which proves to be fatal in this case, as it's creating a `<div id="custom_message"></div>` every single time - therefore, your binding to the `open` function finds the very first instance of `#custom_message` in the HTML, which is no longer the visible one (it's the NEW one that was created on the second invocation).

see:
http://jsfiddle.net/j1v6oxo4/5/

Comment: Marc - Awesome, and thanks for the detailed explanation; much appreciated!